# Sharepoint Listview Javascript turn row color

Tags: sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint and have almost never used JavaScript. I have written a short script just to test and it should turn each row yellow (Under Edit web parts I gave the Listview the location of the script.

When I look in the debugger it seems to see the script but nothing happens. Eventually I want it to change the color based on a value in the List view. But for the moment I just want to get something working.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates.fields = {'Contractdaysleft': { 'View' : HighlightRowOverride }};


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function HighlightRowOverride(inCtx) {

    for (var i = 0; i < inCtx.ListData.Row.length; ++i) {
        var listItem = inCtx.ListData.Row[i];

        var idd = GenerateIIDForListItem(inCtx, listItem);

        var row = document.getElementId(idd);

        row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the template declaration, you need change `overrideCtx.Templates.fields` to `overrideCtx.Templates.Fields`

> The template skeleton is provided below:
>
> ```
> SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
>
>   // OnPreRender: function(ctx) { },
>
>   Templates: {
>
>   //     View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //     Header: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //     Body: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //     Group: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //     Item: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //     Fields: {
>   //         "<field internal name>": {
>   //             View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //             EditForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //             DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
>   //             NewForm: function(ctx) { return ""; }
>   //         }
>   //     },
>   //     Footer: function(ctx) { return ""; }
>
>   },
>
>   // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },
>
> });
> ```

Form another hand, the syntax:

```
Templates: {
      //     Fields: {
      //         "<field internal name>": {
      //             View: function(ctx) { return ""; }
      //         }
      //     }
 }
```

is commonly used for customizing the display of *specific field* in list view.
For highlighting a list view row, i would suggest a slightly different approach (via `OnPostRender` event)  as demonstrated below

**Template example to highlight row in list view**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
       }
     }
   }); 

});
```

**Result**

[image]